# Node with express what is .set() used for?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm learning Node syntax and came across this syntax. What is it used for?

```
server.set('views', __dirname);
```

Comment: Did you check the docs? http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.set

Answer (score 1):

The `.set()` function in express is used to set application settings, which will change the behavior of your application.

In this case, `server.set('views', __dirname);` overwrites the default path for the application's views to the value of `__dirname`.

For more info, see [app.set](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.set) in the express docs, and here is the [list of settings you can modify](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.settings.table).

Answer (score 0):

`set()`, as stated in the [Express API reference](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.set), is used to assign a value to a setting name.  `set()` takes 2 parameters, a `name` and a `value` as such: `set(name, value)`.

So to address the example in your question, `server.set('views', __dirname);` is setting the application's `views` directory to `__dirname`.